# How to solve the timeout problem when pulling image for the first time in a new k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

Usually when I deploy my app in a new k8s cluster, it may timeout due to pulling the image for the first time. Is there any way to solve this issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure kubelet flag `--image-pull-progress-deadline`. By default it equals to 1 minute, you may want to increase it. How to configure kubelet depends on how you installed the cluster.